# Filter function not filtering some texts in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I want to filter rows which contains the text "line" in my google spreasheet. But the filter function is not filtering that word in some cells. What could be the reason?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterlinesthatcontainline() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues().filter(r => !~r.join('').indexOf('line'));
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```